# Elasticsearch Wildcard query returns nothing, why?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, wildcard

Still learning ES. This is my query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { 
            "identifier" : "*NZ*"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have definitely document with a field named `identifier` and a string containing `NZ`. they are returned when I drop the `query` expression.

But I always receive 0 hits when querying this. Why?

Comment: try **nz** lowercase

Comment: that works - but why?

Comment: Because your `identifier` field is probably an analyzed string field, and thus `ABCNZXYZ` would be indexed as `abcnzxyz`. The `wildcard` query does not analyze the term you're searching, so you need to search for `*nz*` instead of `*NZ*`in order to match your `identifier`.

Comment: You will have the same issue when searching with scripts.

Comment: @WaldemarNeto  thx. you'd better write as a answer, cause it helps me.